# Magento2 call WebPixel module after Algolia module

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, search

I have facing issue when 2 modules are overriding the same core Module

```
\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
```

Both are extending same file.

```
In Webpixel
WeltPixel\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute

In Algolia
Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
```

Currently, Algolia Attribute.php is called in frontend, I want to call Webpixel file at last to use isMultiSelect() functionality.

Comment: What about a bridge plugin to \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute with
`aroundApply` could be written base on WeltPixel\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute ?

Comment: I didn't get your point, how to solve the issue, can you please explain more?